# sql server procedure is not returning data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

My Sql Procedure is Working perfectly. But when I call it from Class it does not returns data. And I get this Error. `Column 'Territory_Name' does not belong to table .` I debugged the code and found that All parameters are getting passed correctly, but the procedure is not returning any data. If anyone have idea then please help me.

[image]
[image]

My Stored Procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SPFilterCRMRequests
(
    /* for Time Span */
    @WeekList varchar(50) = null,
    @MonthList varchar(50) = null,
    @YearList varchar(50) = null,
    @QuaterList varchar(50) = null,
    /* for other specific criteria */
    @PriorityList varchar(50) = null,
    @Division_IdList varchar(50) = null,
    @CRM_Service_Type_IdList varchar(50) = null,
    @CRM_Notation_IdList varchar(50) = null,
    @CRM_State_IdList varchar(50) = null,
    @Service_State_IdList varchar(50) = null,
    @Estimated_Amount float

    /* for Designation 
    @Requester varchar(20),
    @Suggester varchar(20) */
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    /*Declare @date3 DateTime = CONVERT(date,'2/8/2013 5:17:00 PM')*/
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    SELECT @sql='SELECT
    CRMDR.Id as Id,  
    LEFT(GEOTREE.GEONAME,15) as Territory_Name,  
    CRMDR.Request_For_Id as Request_For_Id, 
    DRMST.DRNAME as Request_For_Name, 
    USERSTBM.USERNAME as Requester_Name,
    Division.Div_Name as Division_Name,
    USERSABM.USERNAME as Suggester_Name,
    CRMDR.Estimated_Amount as Estimated_Amount, 
    CRMDR.Actual_Amount as Actual_Amount, 
    CRMDR.Compute_Priority as Compute_Priority, 
    CRMNotation.Notation_Name as CRM_Notation_Name,
    CRMServiceType.ServiceName as CRM_Service_Type_Name, 
    CRMDR.Deadline as Deadline, 
    CRMDR.Executed_Date as Executed_Date, 
    CRMDR.Date_Created as Date_Created, 
    CRMDR.Compute_CRM_State as Compute_CRM_State, 
    CRMDR.Compute_Service_State as Compute_Service_State

    From [CRM].[dbo].[CRM_Doctor_Request] AS CRMDR

    JOIN [ASES].[dbo].[USERS] AS USERSTBM
    ON CRMDR.Requester COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = USERSTBM.RID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

    JOIN [ASES].[dbo].[USERS] AS USERSABM
    ON CRMDR.Suggester COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = USERSABM.RID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

    JOIN [ASES].[dbo].[GEOTREE] AS GEOTREE
    ON CRMDR.Territory COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = GEOTREE.RID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

    JOIN [ASES].[dbo].[DRMST] AS DRMST
    ON CRMDR.Request_For_Id COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = DRMST.MDLNO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

    JOIN [CRM].[dbo].[CRM_Request_For_Type] AS CRMReqForType
    ON CRMDR.CRM_Request_For_Type_Id  = CRMReqForType.Id 

    JOIN [CRM].[dbo].[CRM_Notation] AS CRMNotation
    ON CRMDR.CRM_Notation_Id  = CRMNotation.Id 

    JOIN [CRM].[dbo].[CRM_Service_Type] AS CRMServiceType
    ON CRMDR.CRM_Service_Type_Id  = CRMServiceType.Id 

    JOIN [CRM].[dbo].[Division] AS Division
    ON CRMDR.Division_Id  = Division.Id 

    WHERE CRMDR.Is_Deleted=0 '
    If (@MonthList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) in (' + @MonthList + ')  '
    If (@YearList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND (CRMDR.Date_Created) in (' + @YearList + ') '
    If (@WeekList) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateCondition varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50) = 'CRMDR.Date_Created' 
    -- pass the columnname on which condition needs to be aaplied
    EXEC dbo.SPWhereconditionForMultipleWeeks  @WeekList, @ColumnName, @DateCondition OUTPUT
    SELECT @DateCondition
    -- if (LEN(@DateCondition) > 0 )
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND '+ SUBSTRING(@DateCondition, 1, LEN(@DateCondition)-3)
END
If (@QuaterList) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MonthsList varchar(1000)
    EXEC dbo.SPGetMonthsListforMultipleQuaters  @QuaterList, @MonthsList OUTPUT
    SELECT @MonthsList
    -- print @MonthsList
    -- if (LEN(@MonthsList) > 0 )
    SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) in ('
    + SUBSTRING(@MonthsList, 1, LEN(@MonthsList)-1) +')'
END
    If (@PriorityList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Priority in (' + @PriorityList + ') '
    If (@Division_IdList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Division_Id in (' + @Division_IdList + ') '
    If (@CRM_Service_Type_IdList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND CRM_Service_Type_Id in (' + @CRM_Service_Type_IdList + ') '
    If (@CRM_Notation_IdList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND CRM_Notation_Id in (' + @CRM_Notation_IdList + ') '
    If (@Estimated_Amount) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Estimated_Amount > (@Estimated_Amount) '
    If (@CRM_State_IdList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND CRM_State_Id in (' + @CRM_State_IdList + ') '
    If (@Service_State_IdList) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND Service_State_Id in (' + @Service_State_IdList + ') '

    SELECT @sql=@sql + ' ORDER BY CRMDR.Id DESC '
    --print @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N' @MonthList varchar(50), 
    @YearList varchar(50), 
    @QuaterList varchar(50),  
    @PriorityList varchar(50), 
    @Division_IdList varchar(50), 
    @CRM_Service_Type_IdList varchar(50), 
    @CRM_Notation_IdList varchar(50), 
    @Estimated_Amount float, 
    @CRM_State_IdList varchar(50), 
    @Service_State_IdList varchar(50) ', 
         @MonthList, 
         @YearList, 
         @QuaterList, 
         @PriorityList, 
         @Division_IdList, 
         @CRM_Service_Type_IdList, 
         @CRM_Notation_IdList, 
         @Estimated_Amount, 
         @CRM_State_IdList, 
         @Service_State_IdList
RETURN
```

My Class Calling the Procedure :

```
public static List<CRM_Doctor_Request> FilterCRM_Doctor_Request_Details(string WeekList, string MonthList, string YearList, string QuaterList, string PriorityList, string Division_IdList,  string CRM_Service_Type_IdList, string CRM_Notation_IdList, string CRM_State_IdList, string Service_State_IdList, float Estimated_Amount) 
        {
            string proc = "SPFilterCRMRequests";

            List<SqlParameter> arrParam = new List<SqlParameter>();
            SqlParameter pWeekList = new SqlParameter("@WeekList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pMonthList = new SqlParameter("@MonthList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pYearList = new SqlParameter("@YearList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pQuaterList = new SqlParameter("@QuaterList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pPriorityList = new SqlParameter("@PriorityList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pDivision_IdList = new SqlParameter("@Division_IdList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pCRM_Service_Type_IdList = new SqlParameter("@CRM_Service_Type_IdList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pCRM_Notation_IdList = new SqlParameter("@CRM_Notation_IdList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pCRM_State_IdList = new SqlParameter("@CRM_State_IdList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pService_State_IdList = new SqlParameter("@Service_State_IdList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter pEstimated_Amount = new SqlParameter("@Estimated_Amount", SqlDbType.Float);

            pWeekList.Value = WeekList;
            pMonthList.Value = MonthList;
            pYearList.Value = YearList;
            pQuaterList.Value = QuaterList;
            pPriorityList.Value = PriorityList;
            pDivision_IdList.Value = Division_IdList;
            pCRM_Service_Type_IdList.Value = CRM_Service_Type_IdList;
            pCRM_Notation_IdList.Value = CRM_Notation_IdList;
            pCRM_State_IdList.Value = CRM_State_IdList;
            pService_State_IdList.Value = Service_State_IdList;
            pEstimated_Amount.Value = Estimated_Amount;

            arrParam.Add(pWeekList);
            arrParam.Add(pMonthList);
            arrParam.Add(pYearList);
            arrParam.Add(pQuaterList);
            arrParam.Add(pPriorityList);
            arrParam.Add(pDivision_IdList);
            arrParam.Add(pCRM_Service_Type_IdList);
            arrParam.Add(pCRM_Notation_IdList);
            arrParam.Add(pCRM_State_IdList);
            arrParam.Add(pService_State_IdList);
            arrParam.Add(pEstimated_Amount);

            DataTable table = DataProvider.SelectStoreProcedure(proc, arrParam);

            List<CRM_Doctor_Request> ListCRM_Doctor_Request = new List<CRM_Doctor_Request>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                CRM_Doctor_Request CRM_Doctor_RequestObj = new CRM_Doctor_Request();

                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Territory_Name = Convert.ToString(row["Territory_Name"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Request_For_Id = Convert.ToString(row["Request_For_Id"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Request_For_Name = Convert.ToString(row["Request_For_Name"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Requester_Name = Convert.ToString(row["Requester_Name"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Division_Name = Convert.ToString(row["Division_Name"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Suggester_Name = Convert.ToString(row["Suggester_Name"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]);    
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Compute_Priority = Convert.ToString(row["Compute_Priority"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.CRM_Notation_Name = Convert.ToString(row["CRM_Notation_Name"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.CRM_Service_Type_Name = Convert.ToString(row["CRM_Service_Type_Name"]);                    
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Compute_CRM_State = Convert.ToString(row["Compute_CRM_State"]);
                CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Compute_Service_State = Convert.ToString(row["Compute_Service_State"]);

                ListCRM_Doctor_Request.Add(CRM_Doctor_RequestObj);
            }
            return ListCRM_Doctor_Request;
        }
```

code of DataProvider.SelectStoreProcedure:

```
class DataProvider
    {
        public static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect_str"].ConnectionString;

        public static DataTable SelectStoreProcedure(string ProcName, List<SqlParameter> ParaArr)
        {
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ProcName, cn);
                foreach (SqlParameter para in ParaArr)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(data);
                cn.Close();
                return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with your code, although the fact that you enter the foreach loop shows some rows are being returned. You probably want to check the profiler to see exactly what is being passed to the server, and run this and see what the results are. It could be something as trivial as calling the wrong SP because the schema is not defined in your SqlCommand (e.g. calling `MyUserName.SPFilterCRMRequests` instead of `dbo.SPFilterCRMRequests`

Comment: I found that `SPFilterCRMRequests` returns the values returned by subprocedure `SPWhereconditionForMultipleWeeks` in DataTable.

Comment: In which case you need to fill a `DataSet` and the last table in the DataSet will contain the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This looks so messy; Since you are executing more than one query, I think you need to fill data into a `DataSet` and `take the 0th Table` or fill Datatable with results from the correct query.

Also you can reduce your code by half with `Parameters.AddWithValue()` and use `using` with the connection object.

```
//Your method
DataSet data = new DataSet(); //Note Dataset here ****
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect_str"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string proc = "SPFilterCRMRequests";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(proc, cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekList", WeekList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonthList", pMonthList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearList", pYearList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuaterList", pQuaterList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriorityList", pPriorityList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division_IdList", pDivision_IdList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRM_Service_Type_IdList", pCRM_Service_Type_IdList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRM_Notation_IdList", pCRM_Notation_IdList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRM_State_IdList", pCRM_State_IdList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service_State_IdList", pService_State_IdList);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estimated_Amount", pEstimated_Amount);


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cn.Open();
    da.Fill(data);
}

List<CRM_Doctor_Request> ListCRM_Doctor_Request = 
                         new List<CRM_Doctor_Request>();

foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows) //**** Note 0th table here ******
{
 //rest of the code
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to fill a table (with no schema defined)

change `DataTable data = new DataTable();` to `DataSet data = new DataSet();`

and  `DataTable table = data` to `DataTable table = data.Tables[0]`;

and your schema will be automatically generated and everything should work.

**EDIT**

Try building your query up from this setup...

**Define this Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc1] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 x UNION ALL SELECT 2'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

**Create a test app containing just this code**

```
class Program
{
    public const string ConnectionString = @"???";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = Execute("TestProc1");

        Trace.Assert(t.Rows.Count == 2);
    }

    private static DataTable Execute(string sql)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the connection string is your connection string.

That will work and it is functionally equivalent to what you are doing. Once you have that working try building it up to match your specific situation